# How to scrape a public tableau dashboard?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api

Every day I need to downlaod the data available on a public Tableau dashboard. After defining the parameters of interest (time series frequency, time series interval, etc) the dashboard allows you to download the series.

My life would be reasonably easier if I could automate the download of these series to a database using Python or R. I've already tried to analyze the requests made on the page but I couldn't get much further. Is there any way to automate this process?

The dashboard: https://tableau.ons.org.br/t/ONS_Publico/views/DemandaMxima/HistricoDemandaMxima?:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no

Comment: Welcome to SO. The point of asking here, is not to recommend a software or a process ,but to help developers having issues with specific code. Your question is off topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Edit

I've made a [tableau scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) to extract the data from Tableau worksheets

You can get the data from worksheets in a pandas dataframe directly. Also, the parametered values are supported.

The following example get the data from worksheet `Simples Demanda Máxima Ano`, then switch to daily mode, shows the worksheet `Simples Demanda Máxima Semana Dia` data and then set start date to `01/01/2017` :

```py
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://tableau.ons.org.br/t/ONS_Publico/views/DemandaMxima/HistricoDemandaMxima"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
wb = ts.getWorkbook()

# show dataframe with yearly data
ws = wb.getWorksheet("Simples Demanda Máxima Ano")
print(ws.data)

# switch to daily
wb = wb.setParameter("Escala de Tempo DM Simp 4", "Dia")

# show dataframe with daily data
ws = wb.getWorksheet("Simples Demanda Máxima Semana Dia")
print(ws.data)

# switch to daily
wb = wb.setParameter(
    "Início Primeiro Período DM Simp 4", "01/01/2017")

# show dataframe with daily data from 01/01/2017
ws = wb.getWorksheet("Simples Demanda Máxima Semana Dia")
print(ws.data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/TableauStoryPoints)

---

#### Original post

This answer is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962611/how-can-i-scrape-tooltips-value-from-a-tableau-graph-embedded-in-a-webpage/61976399#61976399) but the initial URL page and tableau base URL differ. The process/algo remains the same essentially but I will details the steps :

The graphic is generated in JS from the result of an API :

```
POST https://tableau.ons.org.br/ROOT_PATH/bootstrapSession/sessions/SESSION_ID
```

The `SESSION_ID` parameter is located (among other things) in `tsConfigContainer` textarea in the URL used to build the iframe.

Starting from https://tableau.ons.org.br/t/ONS_Publico/views/DemandaMxima/HistricoDemandaMxima?:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no :

- there is a textarea with id `tsConfigContainer` with a bunch of json values
- extract the `session_id` and root path (`vizql_root`)
- make a POST on `https://tableau.ons.org.br/ROOT_PATH/bootstrapSession/sessions/SESSION_ID` with the `sheetId` as form data
- extract the json from the result (result is not json)

Code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

url = "https://tableau.ons.org.br/t/ONS_Publico/views/DemandaMxima/HistricoDemandaMxima"

r = requests.get(
    url,
    params= {
        ":embed":"y",
        ":showAppBanner":"false",
        ":showShareOptions":"true",
        ":display_count":"no",
        "showVizHome": "no"
    }
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'https://tableau.ons.org.br{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'

r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

print(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"])
```