# Creating a Pandas Dataframe from a Tableau Data Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, tableau-api

I have used this post: [How to scrape a public tableau dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095206/how-to-scrape-a-public-tableau-dashboard) to get the Data Dictionary for this workbook: https://tableau.gatech.edu/t/GT/views/GTCovid-19Tracking/Covid-19DataTable using the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

url = "https://tableau.gatech.edu/t/GT/views/GTCovid-19Tracking/Covid-19DataTable"
r = requests.get(
    url,
    params= {
        ":embed":"y",
        ":showAppBanner":"false",
        ":showShareOptions":"true",
        ":display_count":"no",
        "showVizHome": "no"
    }
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'https://tableau.gatech.edu{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'
r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": 'OverTime Table',
})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

print(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"])
```

But I am not sure how to create a pandas dataframe from the data. The data dictionary obviously does not store it tabular, it uses the indices. Is there a module or a way to transform the dictionary into a dataframe or other tabular format?