# How to scrape a Tableau dashboard in which data is only displayed in a plot after clicking in a map?

Tags: python, web-scraping, click, tableau-api

I am trying to scrape data from [this public Tableau dashboard](https://public.tableau.com/views/MKTScoredeisolamentosocial/VisoGeral). The ineterest is in the time series plotted data. If i click in a spcific state in the map, the time series changes to that specific state. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095206/how-to-scrape-a-public-tableau-dashboard) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962611/how-can-i-scrape-tooltips-value-from-a-tableau-graph-embedded-in-a-webpage/61976399#61976399) posts I got the results for the time series aggregated at the country-level (with the code provided below). But my interest is in a state-level data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

# get the second tableau link
r = requests.get(
    f"https://public.tableau.com/views/MKTScoredeisolamentosocial/VisoGeral",
    params= {
        ":showVizHome":"no"
    }
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)
dataUrl = f'https://public.tableau.com{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'
r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],

})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))


print(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"])
```

I researched about Tableau categories and found out that some parameters can be inserted in the URL to get desirible results, but I was unable to find such parameters. I noticed that the data I want is stored in a worksheet named "time_line_BR", where BR stands for Brazil. But I would like to change this for the states, e.g. São Paulo (SP). I also noted some parameters in tableauData, like "current_view_id", that I suspect can be related to the data being loaded in the time series.

Is is possible to post a request where the data pulled is the same as the one I see in the plots when I manually select a specific state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

I've made [a python library to scrape tableau dashboard](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping). The implementation is more straightforward :

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/MKTScoredeisolamentosocial/VisoGeral"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
dashboard = ts.getDashboard()

for t in dashboard.worksheets:
    #show worksheet name
    print(f"WORKSHEET NAME : {t.name}")
    #show dataframe for this worksheet
    print(t.data)
```

[run this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/TableauDashboard)

---

#### Old answer

When you click on the map, it triggers a call on :

```
POST https://public.tableau.com/{vizql_root}/sessions/{session_id}/commands/tabdoc/select
```

with some form data like the following :

```
worksheet: map_state_mobile
dashboard: Visão Geral
selection: {"objectIds":[17],"selectionType":"tuples"}
selectOptions: select-options-simple
```

It has the state index (here 17) and the worksheet name. I've noticed that the sheet name is either `map_state_mobile` or `map_state (2)` when you click a state.

So, it's necessary to :

- get the state name list to pick a correct index for the state to choose
- make a call the API above to select the state and extract the data

### Extract the field values (state names)

The state are sorted alphabetically (reversed) so the method below is not necessary if you are ok with hardcoding them and sort them like this :

```
['Tocantins', 'Sergipe', 'São Paulo', 'Santa Catarina', 'Roraima', 'Rondônia', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Rio Grande do Norte', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Piauí', 'Pernambuco', 'Paraná', 'Paraíba', 'Pará', 'Minas Gerais', 'Mato Grosso do Sul', 'Mato Grosso', 'Maranhão', 'Goiás', 'Espírito Santo', 'Distrito Federal', 'Ceará', 'Bahia', 'Amazonas', 'Amapá', 'Alagoas', 'Acre']
```

In other case when we don't want to harcode them (for other tableau usecase), execute the method below :

Extracting the state name list is not straightforward since the data is presented as following :

```
{
     "secondaryInfo": {
         "presModelMap": {
            "dataDictionary": {
                "presModelHolder": {
                    "genDataDictionaryPresModel": {
                        "dataSegments": {
                            "0": {
                                "dataColumns": []
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
             "vizData": {
                     "presModelHolder": {
                         "genPresModelMapPresModel": {
                             "presModelMap": {
                                 "map_state (2)": {},
                                 "map_state_mobile": {},
                                 "time_line_BR": {},
                                 "time_line_BR_mobile": {},
                                 "total de casos": {},
                                 "total de mortes": {}
                             }
                         }
                     }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

My method is to get into "vizData" and into a worksheet inside `presModelMap` which has the following structure :

```
"presModelHolder": {
    "genVizDataPresModel": {
        "vizColumns": [],
        "paneColumnsData": {
            "vizDataColumns": [],
            "paneColumnsList": []
        }
    }
}
```

`vizDataColumns` has a collection of object with property `localBaseColumnName`. Find the `localBaseColumnName` with value `[state_name]` with `fieldRole` as `measure` :

```
{
    "fn": "[federated.124ags61tmhyti14im1010h1elsu].[attr:state_name:nk]",
    "fnDisagg": "",
    "localBaseColumnName": "[state_name]", <============================= MATCH THIS
    "baseColumnName": "[federated.124ags61tmhyti14im1010h1elsu].[state_name]",
    "fieldCaption": "ATTR(State Name)",
    "formatStrings": [],
    "datasourceCaption": "federated.124ags61tmhyti14im1010h1elsu",
    "dataType": "cstring",
    "aggregation": "attr",
    "stringCollation": {
        "name": "LEN_RUS_S2",
        "charsetId": 0
    },
    "fieldRole": "measure", <=========================================== MATCH THIS
    "isAutoSelect": true,
    "paneIndices": [
        0  <=========================================== EXTRACT THIS
    ],
    "columnIndices": [
        7  <=========================================== EXTRACT THIS
    ]
}
```

`paneIndices` match the index in the `paneColumnsList` array. And `columnIndices` match the index in the `vizPaneColumns` array. `vizPaneColumns` array is located just in the item selected in `paneColumnsList` array

From there you get the index to search like this :

```
[222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248]
```

In the `dataDictionary` object, get the dataValues (like you've extracted in your question) and extract the state name from the range above

Then you get the state list :

```
['Tocantins', 'Sergipe', 'São Paulo', 'Santa Catarina', 'Roraima', 'Rondônia', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Rio Grande do Norte', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Piauí', 'Pernambuco', 'Paraná', 'Paraíba', 'Pará', 'Minas Gerais', 'Mato Grosso do Sul', 'Mato Grosso', 'Maranhão', 'Goiás', 'Espírito Santo', 'Distrito Federal', 'Ceará', 'Bahia', 'Amazonas', 'Amapá', 'Alagoas', 'Acre']
```

### Call the select endpoint

You just need the worksheet name and the index of the field (state index in the list above)

```
r = requests.post(f'{data_host}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}/commands/tabdoc/select',
    data = {
    "worksheet": "map_state (2)",
    "dashboard": "Visão Geral",
    "selection": json.dumps({
        "objectIds":[int(selected_index)],
        "selectionType":"tuples"
    }),
    "selectOptions": "select-options-simple"
})
```

The code below extract the tableau data, extract the state name with the method above (not necessary if you prefer to hardcode the list), prompt user to enter state index, call the select endpoint and extract the data for this state  :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

data_host = "https://public.tableau.com"

# get the second tableau link
r = requests.get(
    f"{data_host}/views/MKTScoredeisolamentosocial/VisoGeral",
    params= {
        ":showVizHome":"no"
    }
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)
dataUrl = f'{data_host}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'
r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

stateIndexInfo = [ 
    (t["fieldRole"], {
        "paneIndices": t["paneIndices"][0], 
        "columnIndices": t["columnIndices"][0], 
        "dataType": t["dataType"]
    }) 
    for t in data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["vizData"]["presModelHolder"]["genPresModelMapPresModel"]["presModelMap"]["map_state (2)"]["presModelHolder"]["genVizDataPresModel"]["paneColumnsData"]["vizDataColumns"]
    if t.get("localBaseColumnName") and t["localBaseColumnName"] == "[state_name]"
]

stateNameIndexInfo = [t[1] for t in stateIndexInfo if t[0] == 'dimension'][0]

panelColumnList = data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["vizData"]["presModelHolder"]["genPresModelMapPresModel"]["presModelMap"]["map_state (2)"]["presModelHolder"]["genVizDataPresModel"]["paneColumnsData"]["paneColumnsList"]
stateNameIndices = panelColumnList[stateNameIndexInfo["paneIndices"]]["vizPaneColumns"][stateNameIndexInfo["columnIndices"]]["valueIndices"]

# print [222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248]
#print(stateNameIndices)

dataValues = [
    t
    for t in data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"]
    if t["dataType"] == stateNameIndexInfo["dataType"]
][0]["dataValues"]

stateNames = [dataValues[t] for t in stateNameIndices]

# print ['Tocantins', 'Sergipe', 'São Paulo', 'Santa Catarina', 'Roraima', 'Rondônia', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Rio Grande do Norte', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Piauí', 'Pernambuco', 'Paraná', 'Paraíba', 'Pará', 'Minas Gerais', 'Mato Grosso do Sul', 'Mato Grosso', 'Maranhão', 'Goiás', 'Espírito Santo', 'Distrito Federal', 'Ceará', 'Bahia', 'Amazonas', 'Amapá', 'Alagoas', 'Acre']
#print(stateNames)

for idx, val in enumerate(stateNames):
    print(f"{val} - {idx+1}")

selected_index = input("Please select a state by indices : ")
print(f"selected : {stateNames[int(selected_index)-1]}")

r = requests.post(f'{data_host}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}/commands/tabdoc/select',
    data = {
    "worksheet": "map_state (2)",
    "dashboard": "Visão Geral",
    "selection": json.dumps({
        "objectIds":[int(selected_index)],
        "selectionType":"tuples"
    }),
    "selectOptions": "select-options-simple"
})

dataSegments = r.json()["vqlCmdResponse"]["layoutStatus"]["applicationPresModel"]["dataDictionary"]["dataSegments"]
print(dataSegments[max([*dataSegments])]["dataColumns"])
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/TableauScrapeSelectItem)

The code with hardcoding of the state name list is more straightforward :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

data_host = "https://public.tableau.com"

r = requests.get(
    f"{data_host}/views/MKTScoredeisolamentosocial/VisoGeral",
    params= {
        ":showVizHome":"no"
    }
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)
dataUrl = f'{data_host}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'
r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})
stateNames = ['Tocantins', 'Sergipe', 'São Paulo', 'Santa Catarina', 'Roraima', 'Rondônia', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Rio Grande do Norte', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Piauí', 'Pernambuco', 'Paraná', 'Paraíba', 'Pará', 'Minas Gerais', 'Mato Grosso do Sul', 'Mato Grosso', 'Maranhão', 'Goiás', 'Espírito Santo', 'Distrito Federal', 'Ceará', 'Bahia', 'Amazonas', 'Amapá', 'Alagoas', 'Acre']

for idx, val in enumerate(stateNames):
    print(f"{val} - {idx+1}")

selected_index = input("Please select a state by indices : ")
print(f"selected : {stateNames[int(selected_index)-1]}")

r = requests.post(f'{data_host}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}/commands/tabdoc/select',
    data = {
    "worksheet": "map_state (2)",
    "dashboard": "Visão Geral",
    "selection": json.dumps({
        "objectIds":[int(selected_index)],
        "selectionType":"tuples"
    }),
    "selectOptions": "select-options-simple"
})

dataSegments = r.json()["vqlCmdResponse"]["layoutStatus"]["applicationPresModel"]["dataDictionary"]["dataSegments"]
print(dataSegments[max([*dataSegments])]["dataColumns"])
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/TableauScrapeSelectedItemHardcoded)

Note that, in this case, even if we don't care about the output of the first call (`/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}`). It's needed to validate the session_id and call the select call afterwards (otherwise the select doesn't return anything)